# When creating a 'status' entry with the statuses module, stop it from creating a double post

Tags: views, 7

Am using [statuses](http://drupal.org/project/statuses) 7.x-1.0-unstable4+43-dev. I've spoken to some of the "maintainers" on the drupal.org site and none have been able to answer this question, blamed another module or have ignored my question. So I'm taking this question to the greatest site on earth, [Stack Exchange!](http://www.stackexchange.com).

When I create a 'status' from a user profile page. It create 1 entry in the DB but displays a duplicate of the entry on the user page. According to the one of the maintainers, its an issues with views. I've tried to tinker with views to no avail. I was also told it was a problem with one of the contrib submodules... The problem with that is.. I ONLY HAVE THE MAIN MODULE ENABLED! So, do you gurus have any idea why this would create a duplicate display of a single entry in statuses?

Comment: To be fair to the maintainers, they marked the branch unstable.  Modules marked unstable aren't guaranteed to work (or work properly); that's why they're marked unstable.  A quick look at the project page reveals a large number of show-stopping bugs at the moment: http://drupal.org/node/1551542

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, never posted here before, but the rules seem kind of draconian. I don't have a fix for this, but I thought I could relate that I've had the exact same problem and note some of the things I've tried.

I notice than when I look at the View under "Preview" and specify a user_id, it works perfectly. My hope is that IceCreamYou (the main contributor, who is particularly arrogant, when you read his responses to questions) will stumble upon this and a lightbulb will go off in his head.

Otherwise, my suggestion would be to intercept the SQL (you can see it with the Devel module), try to roll your own (with the inclusion of the DISTINCT keyword, which when I add it to the query generated removes the duplicates).

Note that the code for the "statuses" view is embedded in the Statuses module, so you'll have to extract it from there first.

If this sort of post is against the rules, feel free to delete it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've last looked at this project 6 months ago and there seems to be a lot of development on it. However, IMHO, it looks like an ambitious project with tons of integrations which to me means "complexity".

Not sure what your requirements are but you might be able to do most with content types, custom fields and/or comments in Drupal 7, possibly combined with views.

For example, checkout [Ajax Comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) for a cool ajax submit without having to reload the page.

Comment: I'm trying to put together a 'wall' similar to fb's. It would just need to show content/comment creation, and messages that users can send to each other. Messages would need to have a privacy option. I liked the activities integration it WAS supporting.